# Defining a function to use in another function dependent on similar parameters

Tags: functions, expression-construction

I want to define a variable dependent function which can be used to define another function which depends on the same variable and other variables.

For example, I have a system where I define abundance of `c[i, j, t]` per unit time using this:

```
eqs = 
  Table[D[c[i, j, t], t] == k[j - 1] s[i] - (k[j] s[i] + d[j]) c[i, j, t], 
    {i, 1, 5}, {j, 0, 10}];
```

I can calculate total size of the `c[i, j, t]` population by this:

```
NC = Sum[c[i, j, t], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 10}]
```

Now, what I want to do is write a function such that I can make `s[i]` in the equation dependent on `NC` (total population size) at time 't'. Basically, I want a function which can evaluate `NC` at time `t` and use that value to calculate `s[i]`. This `s[i]` value then will be use to calculate NC at time `t + 1`.

I was thinking of using pure functions, but I have not been able to figure out my way through it.

Comment: If you look at `Nc`, you will see that it contains only terms of the form c[i,j,t], it contains no terms of the form s[i]. I suspect that your table has not done what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach illustrated in a simplified system.  First define `s[i]` as desired

```
Nc := Sum[c[i, t], {i, 2}]
s[i_] := (i/Nc)^2
```

and then create, solve, and plot the system of ODEs.

```
eqs = Table[D[c[i, t], t] == s[i] c[i, t], {i, 2}];
var = Table[c[i, t], {i, 2}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqs, Thread[var == 1] /. t -> 0}, var, {t, 0, 2}];
Plot[sol, {t, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {t, c}]
```

[image]